# jQuery count non-empty fields

Tags: jquery

Trying to count the number of input fields of class '.booked' that are NOT empty (ie they have some kind of value entered.

For some reason this is not doing it for me. Someone please put me out of my misery :)

```
$('input.booked:not(:empty)').length
```

Comment: From Docs. ":empty" selects all elements that have no children (including text nodes)

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```
$('input.booked[value!=""]').length
```

`empty` returns nodes with no children, which isn't what you want.

Answer (score 5):

the [`:empty`](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/) selector filters to elements that have no child nodes. What you want is an [attribute equals](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) selector...

```
$("input.booked:not([value=''])").length
```